# script fails when "mv" clubbed with "ftp"

Tags: shell, unix, ftp, mv

I tried including a mv command with ftp command, in a script file. But when i run that script file, it fails on the mv command.

Code:

```
/usr/bin/ftp -i -n $HOST <<END_FTP
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd /home/infodba/temploc/test_script/
binary
mget Cust*.txt
mv Cust*.txt ./archive
quit
END_FTP

exit 0
```

It throws this error: "?Invalid command"

The same script works if i remove the mv command from the file

Is there workaround?

Answer (score 1):

`mv` is not a valid ftp command.  If you're trying to move the files you've just acquired to ./archive, you need to either exit ftp first, or escape the command with a `!`.

`!mv Cust*.txt ./archive`

Comment: i actually intend to move files on remote machine, not local

Comment: if you want to move the files in the remote, use ssh to login to remote host and scp the remote files to destination/local machine and move the files in the remote host.

Comment: Then you can't do it in ftp.  I suppose you _could_ `mput` the files you've just fetched, but that would be ridiculously inefficient.  You'll need to 'ssh' to the remote server instead.

Answer (score 0):

mv command is not supported by ftp/sftp (i.e) you can't move the files in the remote host, But with **bang ( ! )** you will be able to execute the commands in your localhost.

After getting the files from remote host if you are trying to move files in localhost below works.

```
/usr/bin/ftp -i -n $HOST <<END_FTP
...
mget Cust*.txt
!mv Cust*.txt ./archive
...
...
END_FTP
```